# Injection when using spring and mysql

Tags: mysql, spring

I am using MySQL as back end and Spring as Frame work
I know that spring does not support injection, does that mean that the database is secure and i don't have to handle injection in MySQL?

Comment: do you mean SQL Injection? Spring support Injection though bean Injection?

Comment: yes SQL injection. ok if spring supports injection ,does mysql support injection also? if yes, can i handle injection from mysql database or that should be done through spring?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Spring (MVC) SQL injection avoidance?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8472608/spring-mvc-sql-injection-avoidance)

Answer (score 0):

[SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) is something that you definitely want to avoid. It's not something that a database or framework supports. It's an attack. Something that you want to avoid. And it won't be solved by any framework.

You have to understand what SQL injection attacks are and when they can happen, and adopt good practices of coding to avoid them: always use [prepared statements](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html) and never create SQL queries dynamically by appending values coming from untrusted sources.

In short, instead of doing

```
String sql = "select a, b from some_table where d = '" + valueEnteredByUser + "'";
```

do the following:

```
String sql = "select a, b from some_table where d = ?"
```

and then create a prepared statement and bind `valueEnteredByUser` to the query parameter.

It's as simple as that.